# Remove hash in URL (fullpage.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting, single-page-application, fullpage.js

I'm using the plugin [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Instead of hash urls for the sections like `example.com/#sectionname)`, I would like clean URLs like `example.com/sectionname`.

The plugin doesn't provide this option but I'm curious if there is a simple enough way to achieve this regardless.

**Update 1:**
I've tried this callback:

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    if (nextIndex == 2) {
        history.replaceState(null, null, "/about")
    }
}
```

as well as this:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    if (index == 2) {
        history.replaceState(null, null, "/about");
    }
}
```

However, when I scroll to the second section, the URL is like this: `www.example.com/about/#about`.

I've also tried this code:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#about") {
        history.replaceState(null, null, "/about");
    }
}
window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

However, when new sections are loaded the hash briefly shows before changing to the non hash URL.

Comment: Already answered in the github issues: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2022

Comment: Your answer was just that the plugin doesn't have an option, which I already know. I'm wondering if there is a different way to do this.

Comment: fair enough. My answer down here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always make use of the HTML 5 history API. 
You can use callbacks such as `onLeave` or `afterLoad` for that:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        history.pushState(null, null, "bar.html");
    }
});
```

Take into account you'll need to use some polyfill for old browsers. Or just use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) directly.

Note the example above might not work on localhost on some browsers. You'd better try it in a server.

Comment: Just do not use the anchors option then. Or use `lockAnchors:true`

Comment: I want history and forward/back functionality. I like the logic you've written and am having a hard time getting everything to work right writing my own.  Basically I think fullpage is perfect but I just don't want hashes in the URLs. Could you point me in the right direction on how to modify the plugin perhaps?

Comment: @Benjamin it is not easy. That's why it is not implemented :D

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!